# Speech recognition with machine learning

Tags: c#, ml.net

How could I use *ML.NET* to improve speech recognition? For example instead of writing loads of commands, could I just use machine learning for the program, so it gradually learns to understand voice commands and will be able to execute them?

Are there any data sets that I can use for training or should I create my own data? Would it be better to use a SQL server or something else?

Comment: This use case may be better suited for the Speech Services - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speaker-recognition/

Comment: Hi toborm, welcome to [SO]. Please take our [tour], it only takes a minute. Your question seems to be a bit broad. Have you tried something? A [MCVE] with your current attempt may help.

Comment: @Jon what do you mean?

Comment: @EnderLook I have no code im using ml.net  in order for me to build a machine learning model I must add data im wondering what type of data i would need for this type of scenario I can either add csv. file or SQL server data base.